# Python: ImportError from compiled source code

Tags: python, cryptography, padding, importerror, pyinstaller

I'm having problems while running a compiled source code. The code itself is correct and if I run `python file.py` everything goes fine; if I compile it with pyinstaller or software like this, and then I run the compiled file it says `ImportError: No module named _cffi_backend`. But when I open python and import cffi and/or _cffi_backend python doesn't show error. Investigating in my code I found that the problem is just with `padding` from [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography), so if I don't import `padding` the output doesn't show errors (obviously errors comes because the code doesn't work well without padding module).
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this issue as well.

What worked for me was adding in `--hidden-import=_cffi_backend` option when building with pyinstaller.